ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework_simplejwt'
I am experiencing an issue with rest_framework_simplejwt when I try to run migrations in my Django project. The error I encounter is:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework_simplejwt'

I have verified that the library is installed:
pip show djangorestframework-simplejwt 
Name: djangorestframework-simplejwt 
Version: 3.2.2 
Summary: A minimal JSON Web Token authentication plugin for Django REST Framework Home-page: https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt Author-email: davesque@gmail.com License: MIT Location: \Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages 
Requires: django, djangorestframework, pyjwt Required-by:

My INSTALLED_APPS includes the necessary applications:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'app',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist'
]

Here are my REST_FRAMEWORK settings:
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}

And my SIMPLE_JWT settings:
from datetime import timedelta
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),
    "ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS": True,
    "BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION": True,
    "UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN": False,

    "ALGORITHM": "HS256",
    "SIGNING_KEY": SECRET_KEY,
    "VERIFYING_KEY": "",
    "AUDIENCE": None,
    "ISSUER": None,
    "JSON_ENCODER": None,
    "JWK_URL": None,
    "LEEWAY": 0,

    "AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ("Bearer",),
    "AUTH_HEADER_NAME": "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION",
    "USER_ID_FIELD": "id",
    "USER_ID_CLAIM": "user_id",
    "USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE": "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule",

    "AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES": ("rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken",),
    "TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM": "token_type",
    "TOKEN_USER_CLASS": "rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser",

    "JTI_CLAIM": "jti",

    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM": "refresh_exp",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),

    "TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenObtainPairSerializer",
    "TOKEN_REFRESH_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenRefreshSerializer",
    "TOKEN_VERIFY_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenVerifySerializer",
    "TOKEN_BLACKLIST_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenBlacklistSerializer",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenObtainSlidingSerializer",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenRefreshSlidingSerializer",
}

I don't understand where the problem comes from. I would appreciate any help to identify the issue.
What I have tried:

Installing different versions of djangorestframework-simplejwt
Verifying the library installation
Checking the configurations in settings.py

None of these steps have resolved the issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

Getting a ModuleNotFound despite pip telling you it's installed, points towards an environment/path issue. If I were to guess, you probably are not using a virtual environment? Try setting up venv, activate an environment, install all your packages there, then try running your app.

Follow the instruction that  @Vegard gave you, after that run commnad pip list where you can find all installed module

Please provide us with the whole error log. Because python writes on which line you got the error. Maybe your error is issued in the simpleJWT repository: https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt/issues/603

Agreed with @Vegard, however instead of venv use poetry, it will make your life less stressful.
